# How to find out database migration logs on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to rollback my database to a certain version on Rails using the STEP parameter, but I don't know how many steps should i rollback so I want to check the migration log. Can I do that on Rails (v3.2.13)?

Comment: Do you know the specific migration upto which you want to rollback

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

It will give you the following output, `up` meaning migration has been run, `down` hasn't been run yet:

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20120328154345  Devise create users
   up     20120331182021  Create websites
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get migration versions 
by

```
 >  ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
   (38.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
 => 20130403113845 
1.9.3-p392 :002 > ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions
   (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
 => [20130327085819, 20130327085820, 20130327085821, 20130327085822, 20130327085823, 20130327085824, 20130327085825, 20130327085826, 20130327085827, 20130327085828, 20130327085829, 20130327085830,........
```

or you can use the time stamp of the specific migration upto which you want to rollback and use

rake db:migrate:down VERSION= timestamp